# React Native Version Mismatch Error

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run a react native application using the following command.

```
npm run android
```

I get the following error.

[image]

im using nvm - `nvm use stable`

Now using node v8.9.4 (npm v4.6.1)

```
**package.json**

{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.11.0",
    "jest-expo": "23.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^23.0.4",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.50.3"
  }
}
```

A different solution recommended rerunning the build process because there maybe some interference, but this did not work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to solve this my self. The error message was showing a react-native version of `0.50.3`.

But the latest version is `0.52` as can be seen here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/versions.html.

So i updated package json to reflect this.

```
  "dependencies": {

    "react-native": "0.52"
  }
```

then i deleted npm modules and reran `npm install`. This fixed my issue.

tldr; update package.json react-native dependency to reflect latest version.

Comment: You should probably also upgrade your `expo` and `jest-expo` dependencies to version `25`, as that is the version of Expo that officially supports React Native `0.52`.

Comment: Hmm why are the installing older versions? Is it because npm is at v4 to bypass the npm5 compatibility issue?

Comment: I don't know what happened there. Maybe you had a newer Expo client installed on your emulator? Or could be a NPM bug, too. Based on your package.json, it should've resolved to Expo 23 with came with React Native 0.50.

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem, and the KHAN give us the right solution.

I'm Putting here the package.json for thoses who need the fix:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.11.0",
    "jest-expo": "25.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.52"
  }
}
```